# Skip bad records on Select statement

Tags: sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safe-casting text to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724440/safe-casting-text-to-xml)

I am using a stored procedure where I am selecting records (which is more than 80000) and inserting those records into another table. My query is below for selecting records which is inside stored procedure.

```
SELECT EmployeeID,CAST(EmployeeInformation AS xml) as ei, CreatedTimeStamp 
FROM Employee WITH (NOLOCK)
```

`EmployeeInformation` column contains XML data in string format. (I can not change the format of column)

My issue is, in case of any bad XML data in `EmployeeInformation` The *Select* query is failing and for which the stored procedure is failing.

eg. of bad XML : `<Employee><EmployeeID></EmployeeI></Employee>` [Here start tag `EmployeeID` is not same as end tag `EmployeeI`]

Is there any way that I can skip the bad XML record and fetch other records in *Select* query?  Also, is there any way for me to keep track of the skipped record?

Answer (score 0):

I think when the EmployeeID element ends with EmployeeI without D at the end, the xml parser can't let you to do query on your incorrect data. You might want to write a parser to detect that, but I certainly do not suggest that way. Correcting input might be a better way. Remember that when your input has a problem, fix it! do not clear the question to solve it. Also it does not matter how large your xml data is and as you already chosen, xml data type would be the best datatype for the storing column.

Cheers